# в чем разница в селекте с not null и без?

Tags: sql

ссылка на задачку: https://www.sql-ex.ru/learn_exercises.php#answer_ref 
решение:

```
select name from battles
where datepart(year,date) not in 
(select launched from ships
join classes on classes.class = ships.class
where launched is not null
union
select launched from ships
join outcomes on ships.name = outcomes.ship
where launched is not null)
```

вопрос: почему без (is not null) не проходит проверку? 
что происходит когда мы сравниваем например: дата not in (и тут null)?

Comment: Почитай, как ведёт себя WHERE IN, когда в списке есть NULL.

Comment: @Akina но тут же не должно быть null в списке

Comment: Это ещё почему? Может, корабль ещё строится...

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ссылку на статью про null в where not in на английском 
https://www.polderknowledge.nl/2018/03/02/sql-beware-null-where-not/
Если вкратце то нельзя сравнивать с null т.к сравнение с null всегда возвращает null. Поэтому в where not in нужно сравнивать только с not null.